# Access 2007 VBA - Open Two Excel Workbooks

Tags: vba, ms-access-2007

I am using Access 2007.  In my Access file I have VBA code that opens an Excel
workbook when the Access program begins.  The Excel workbook remains open
while the program is running.  I use this code to open the workbook:

```
Public xl As Object
Public wb1 As Object
Set xl = New Excel.Application
Set wb1 = xl.Workbooks.Open("c:\Book1.xlsx")
```

Now while the program is running I may need to open a second Excel workbook,
get some data from it, then close it.  I used this code:

```
Public wb2 As Object
Set wb2 = xl.Workbooks.Open("c:\Book2.xlsx")
```

But this doesn't work.  It seems that the first workbook may have closed because
if I do debug.print Workbooks.Count the response is "0".

Any suggestions on how to open a second workbook and still have the first workbook open?
Should I create a second instance of Excel and use that to open the second workbook?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You may have more luck with this procedure instead:

```
Sub OpenExcel(fName As String)
    Dim xlApp As Object
    On Error Resume Next
    Set xlApp = GetObject(, "Excel.Application")
    If Err.Number <> 0 Then
        'Excel wasn't running, start it from code
        Set xlApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
    End If
    On Error GoTo 0
xlApp.Workbooks.Open (fName)
End Sub
```

With your code it's possible that Excel was opening but the second workbook did not default to **visible**, which could be set with `xl.Visible = True`.  Alternatively, a second `xl` object could have helped.

Regardless, this method is safer is a number of ways.

Make sure when you're done, make sure you clean up (and free up memory) with something like `xlApp.Quit` and `Set xlApp = Nothing`.

In fact, I'd suggest you reboot right now... before you do, take a look at the running processes in your Task Manager - I wouldn't be surprised if you have several "invisible" instances of Excel running.  :)

Comment: @Curtis -  btw, *Access '07 huh... ouch* -- just in case you didn't know, you can get the newest version of Office for free from Microsoft (no strings; not a trial) if you're a [student](https://www.microsoft.com/en-ca/education/products/office/default.aspx) **or** a [developer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/developer-program/office-365-developer-program).  ;)

Comment: Hi.  I just tried to send some sample code to get your opinion, but I was told the text was way too long.  Can I send a message directly to you, or e-mail you?

Comment: You can **[edit]** your question to add examples or other relevant information, plus this keeps everything organized and in one "public" place, with the intent of being a repository of answers (rather than a "free coding service")to help others in the future. I'm not sure how much code you tried to add (hitting the 600 character limit for a comment or the 35KB limit for a post?!)  When posting code it's important to submit as little code as is necessary to reproduce the problem.  See: **[mcve]**.

Comment: @CurtisD - Did my answer not work for you?  What's the issue?

Comment: I took your suggestion and created a second xl object.  I wanted to run it by you.

Comment: Update - Your SUB did not return a reference to the workbook that was opened.  So I tried the following code:

    OpenExcel "c:\Book1.xlsx"
    Set objWorkBook1 = xlApp.Workbooks("c:\Book1.xlsx")

However an error occurred: Subscript out of range.